# JavaFX main application won't start

Tags: exception, javafx, runtime

I need to get this working for an exam in my cisc class, but java and I don't seem to get a long very well. I keep getting these errors on start up and I have searched everywhere for an answer, and just don't get it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong...?

These are the main method and the fxml I am trying to link to it. There isn't much of anything there at the moment because I am just trying to make it run.

```
package main;
import java.io.IOException;

import calculator.view.calcController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

        private Stage primaryStage;
        private AnchorPane Layout;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            this.primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");

            this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file: C://Users/Amanda/Documents/1427173308_Address_Book.png"));

            initRootLayout();

        }

        /**
         * Initializes the root layout.
         */
        @FXML
        public void initRootLayout() {
            try {
                // Load root layout from fxml file.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(main.Main.class.getResource("view/Layout.fxml"));
                Layout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

                // Show the scene containing the root layout.
                Scene scene = new Scene(Layout);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);

                // Give the controller access to the main app.
                calcController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setMain(this);

                primaryStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get. I have tried changing the location to everything I can imagine, but it just won't work.

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknow`enter code here`n Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1108411398.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at main.Main.initRootLayout(Main.java:39)
    at main.Main.start(Main.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1905880089.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1184208461.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: The problem here is you're mistaken in : ("view/Layout.fxml"). Have you created your fxml file ? have you really put it in the package view ? check if the name is spelled correctly. Line : 38

Comment: As Calips says the problem is in the fxml file name. Try to replace main.Main.class by only Main.class or just getClass().